# "add comment" button missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I can only "add comment" on questions and answers posted by myself, not others. The button is missing. Why is that?

I use the linux version of firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have enough reputation yet yet. You need 50 reputation to "comment everywhere."

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment